# Can I use Python's CSV reader with Google Fusion Tables?

Tags: python, csv, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to read data from Google Fusion Tables API into Python using the *csv* library. It seems like querying the API returns CSV data, but when I try and use it with *csv.reader*, it seems to mangle the data and split it up on every character rather than just on the commas and newlines. Am I missing a step? Here's a sample I made to illustrate, using a public table:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import urllib2, urllib

request_url = 'https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query' 
query = 'SELECT * FROM 1140242 LIMIT 10'

url = "%s?%s" % (request_url, urllib.urlencode({'sql': query}))
serv_req = urllib2.Request(url=url)
serv_resp = urllib2.urlopen(serv_req)

reader = csv.reader(serv_resp.read())

for row in reader:
    print row #prints out each character of each cell and the column headings
```

Ultimately I'd be using the *csv.DictReader* class, but the base *reader* shows the issue as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`csv.reader()` takes in a file-like object.

Change

```
reader = csv.reader(serv_resp.read())
```

to

```
reader = csv.reader(serv_resp)
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(serv_resp)
```

Comment: perfect thank you, I knew I was misunderstanding how something was supposed to be used

Answer (score 1):

It's not the CSV module that's causing the problem. Take a look at the output from `serv_resp.read()`. Try using `serv_resp.readlines()` instead.